# pass form using ajax get to controller method

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm new in MVC programming so please excuse any possible stupidity in this question.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnGenerate").click(function () {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '/Main/MyMethod',  
                    data: JSON.stringify($('#searchForm').serializeArray()),                
                    dataType: 'json',
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                        alert(errorThrown);
                    }
                })
                return false;
            });
        });
```

And my method in the controller:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public FileStreamResult MyMethod(MyModel r)
        {
          return null;
        }
```

I do get 500 Internal server error.

Comment: What model is passed into this view?

Comment: @model MyModel .

Comment: My answer should fix this issue then

Comment: Will you include the MyModel class and its properties? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using `serialize()` instead of `serializeArray()`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
        url: '/Main/MyMethod',  
        data: JSON.stringify($('#searchForm').serialize()),                
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        alert(errorThrown);
    }
})
```

Also you could try changing the method attribute to `HttpPost`:

```
[HttpPost]
public FileStreamResult MyMethod(MyModel r)
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Great. I will try. Also you should edit your answer, as it contains serializeArray(), right?

Comment: Still same error. I tried: data: JSON.stringify($('#searchForm').serialize()),

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing post,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
        url: '/Main/MyMethod',  
        data: {
//your MyModel properties e.g. name
name: "MyName",
age: 1
    },


        success: function(data){
    },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        alert(errorThrown);
    }
})
```

Comment: I do not want to post data, why to use POST and not GET then?

Comment: I do not know what you want to achieve with the code above. like do you want to submit the form in order to generate a file? then just use a form submit. do not use ajax.

or do you need to submit a form -> save, delete, edit. -> return Json response. but I think it's the first one.

Comment: I will create a file, based on the model values. This is the reason i want to pass the model.

Comment: The error 500 means you're ajax call is not getting through your controller. its because it's expecting a model yet you did not provide one. If you need to create a file base on the form values. why not do it through form submission instead through ajax?

Comment: I want to generate the file base on form values through other button, not the submit one. The submit one is used for something else.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $("#_frmId").submit(function(){
        event.preventDefault();    // Prevent the default behaviour of the form.

        var formdata = $("#_frmId").serialize();    // Serializes the form

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("// Method", "// Controller")',
            type:'POST',
            data: formdata,
            success: function(result){
                // Do whatever
            }
        });
    });
})
```

`_frmId` the ID of the form.

When the form is submitted, it will call this method.

Also, there is no need to stringify the data passed to the controller as you are serialising it.

What you are passing to the controller is the View's model not the form model.

So your controller action should be something like

```
public FileStreamResult MyMethod(//<The View model> r)
```

Finally you are posting data to the controller so remove the `[HttpGet]`

Comment: Also, no need to use [HttpPost]?

Comment: I do not want to post data, I do want only to get the model. That's why I don't want to use post

Comment: @Akhtubir no. You can add it but there is no need to

Comment: @Akhtubir What do you mean? You can still return from a POST

Comment: I still get: jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:51014/Main/MyMethod 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0):

If serialize doesn't work, This approach can also be tried.

```
$("#my_form").submit(function(event){
event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
var request_method = $(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //Encode form elements for submission

`$.ajax({
    url : post_url,
    type: request_method,
    data : form_data
}).done(function(response){ //
    $("#server-results").html(response);
});
```

})`